# How do I replace every x element of a list?

Tags: python, list, element

For example:

```
l = ["a", "l", "a", "m", "a", "n", "t"]
```

In this case I want to change every "a" in the list to "e", like this:

```
l = ["e", "l", "e", "m", "e", "n", "t"]
```

I tried indexing and stuff, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You don't replace every x element, but specific element/value with another value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension.

```
In [1]: l = ["a", "l", "a", "m", "a", "n", "t"]

In [2]: d = {"a": "e"}

In [3]: l = [d.get(i, i) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
Out[4]: ['e', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't']
```